# how to get menus displayed in the sample website

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, drop-down-menu

I am creating website and i am trying to create menus similar to the below site

[drop menu](http://www.snapdeal.com/)

```
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float: inherit;">
                <li class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li id="categoryDropDownId" class="dropdown col-sm-2"><a
                    href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-center">SEE ALL CATEGORY
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                    <ul id="dropdownMenuId" class="dropdown-menu pull-right"
                        style="min-width: 196px;">
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 5</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 6</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 7</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 8</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 9</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 10</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 11</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"
                            class="dropdown-toggle" id="sampleLinkId">Dropdown Link 12</a> <!-- <div class="" id="addFrame" style="z-index: 0; background-color: black;"> -->
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"
                                style="margin-top: -310; height: 370px; z-index: 1;">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 12.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 12.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 12.3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 12.4</a></li>
                            </ul></li>
                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"
                            class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown Link 13</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu"
                                style="margin-top: -310; height: 370px; z-index: 1;">
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 13.1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 13.2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 13.3</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"
                                    class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                                        Submenu Link 13.4</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.2</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"
                                            class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                                                Submenu Link 13.4.3</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.3.1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.3.2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.3.3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.3.4</a></li>
                                            </ul></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#"
                                            class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown
                                                Submenu Link 13.4.4</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.4.1</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.4.2</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.4.3</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 13.4.4.4</a></li>
                                            </ul></li>
                                    </ul></li>
                            </ul></li>
                    </ul></li>

                <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="col-sm-1"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

but i have tried above code, but nothing works for me.

please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j50psj21/2/)

i have attached my page below[image]

Edit:- i have attached my screen shot , what i have achieved so far is, i can able to get sub menus inside menus, but when i hover menu, i need menu along with some background images. i don't know how to achieve this, i am using bootstrap css for menu alignment.

Comment: The code in your fiddle contains over 13000 lines of CSS. That's way too much for anyone here to wade through and figure out what your problem is. Please update it so that only the minimum required code is included to reproduce your problem. Also, it would help a great deal if you could describe what you are trying to achieve with the CSS, so that we know what to look for in helping you.

Comment: (And by describe what you're trying to achieve I mean explain it in terms of "when the user does X, my menu should do Y", not just pointing to another website)

Comment: i have updated the fiddle, i am using bootstrap css for menu alignment